# Why do I have missing keybindings for magit in spacemacs?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I am trying to use magit in spacemacs. When I read instructions to use magit, I am instructed to hit <kbd>spc</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>. However, when I push <kbd>spc</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> I see only one shortcut which is <kbd>spc</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>, which is "helm-ls-git-ls". Why do I not have any of the other keybindings? I have checked to make sure magit is installed, and also I have reinstalled the package, but I still not get any of the keybindings.
I am at a loss. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. In my spacemacs dotfile, under my layers function, I had the line git commented out. I have since enabled the git layer and I now have all the associated magit commands.